# How to use Embedded Debezium for multiple databases in a single Postgres server?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, debezium

Let's say we have two microservices: `service_A` and `service_B`.
Each one has its own database (`db_a` and `db_b` respectively) in a single Postgres server instance (*This is just a staging environment, so we don't have a cluster*).

There is also another service, `service_debezium` (with an *Embedded Debezium v1.6.1Final*) that should be listening for changes in `db_a` and `db_b`. So basically there are two Debezium engines configured in this service.

But somehow `service_debezium` cannot listen for `db_a` and `db_b` at the same time. It only listens for one of them for some reason and there are no error logs.

Additionally, if I configure `service_debezium` (i.e. its Debezium engine) to listen for either `db_a` or `db_b`, it works just as expected so I'm certain their configuration properties are correct, and (when there is only one engine) everything is working.

1. So why can't we use multiple Debezium engines to listen for multiple databases in a single Postgres server? What am I missing here?
2. Another alternative I thought is to use just one Debezium engine that listens for all databases in that Postgres server instance but apparently it requires `database.dbname` in its configuration so I guess the preferred way is to define a new Debezium engine for each database. Is that correct?

Here are the Debezium configurations in `service_debezium`:

- `db_a` config bean:

```java
  @Bean
  public io.debezium.config.Configuration dbAConnector() throws IOException {
    File offsetStorageTempFile = File.createTempFile("offsets_", ".dat");
    File dbHistoryTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbhistory_", ".dat");
    return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
        .with("name", "db_a_connector")
        .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector")
        .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
        .with("offset.storage.file.filename", offsetStorageTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
        .with("database.hostname", "localhost")
        .with("database.port", 5432)
        .with("database.user", "postgres")
        .with("database.password", "*****")
        .with("database.dbname", "db_a")
        .with("table.whitelist", "public.dummy_table,public.another_dummy_table")
        .with("plugin.name", "pgoutput")
        .with("slot.name", "db_a_connector")
        .with("database.server.name", "db_a_server")
        .with("database.history", "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
        .with("database.history.file.filename", dbHistoryTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .build();
  }
```

- `db_b` config bean:

```java
  @Bean
  public io.debezium.config.Configuration dbBConnector() throws IOException {
    File offsetStorageTempFile = File.createTempFile("offsets_", ".dat");
    File dbHistoryTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbhistory_", ".dat");
    return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
        .with("name", "db_b_connector")
        .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector")
        .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
        .with("offset.storage.file.filename", offsetStorageTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
        .with("database.hostname", localhost)
        .with("database.port", 5432)
        .with("database.user", "postgres")
        .with("database.password", "*****")
        .with("database.dbname", "db_b")
        .with("table.whitelist", "public.yet_another_table")
        .with("plugin.name", "pgoutput")
        .with("slot.name", "db_b_connector")
        .with("database.server.name", "db_b_server")
        .with("database.history", "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
        .with("database.history.file.filename", dbHistoryTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .build();
  }
```

Here are how I create Debezium engine instances in `service_debezium`:

- `db_a` listener:

```java
@Component
public class DBAListener {

  public DBAListener(
      @Qualifier("dbAConnector") Configuration connectorConfiguration /*, ... other services */) {

    this.debeziumEngine = DebeziumEngine.create(ChangeEventFormat.of(Connect.class))
        .using(connectorConfiguration.asProperties())
        .notifying(this::handleChangeEvent)
        .build();

    // ...
  }

  // ...

}
```

- and similarly `db_b` listener:

```java
@Component
public class DBBListener {

  public DBBListener(
      @Qualifier("dbBConnector") Configuration connectorConfiguration /*, ... other services */) {

    this.debeziumEngine = DebeziumEngine.create(ChangeEventFormat.of(Connect.class))
        .using(connectorConfiguration.asProperties())
        .notifying(this::handleChangeEvent)
        .build();

    // ...
  }

  // ...

}
```

- `postgresql.conf`:

```
# ...other conf

wal_level = logical             # minimal, archive, hot_standby, or logical (change requires restart)
# max number of walsender processes (i.e. # of replica databases + # of Debezium engines) (change requires restart)
# Abrupt streaming client disconnection might cause an orphaned connection slot until a timeout is reached, 
# so this parameter should be set slightly higher than the maximum number of expected clients 
# so disconnected clients can immediately reconnect
max_wal_senders = 3
max_replication_slots = 3       # max number of replication slots (change requires restart)
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: Updated the code snippets to give a full example according to [@Yuri Niitsuma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040487/5492826).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a debezium connector, it create a replication slot with the default name "debezium". Then you try to create another instance and try to create a replication slot with the same name and cannot use two instances at the same time using the same replication slot, that will throw a error. This is the poor explanation, but I'll give the solution.

Add on each connector this configuration:

On dbAConnector

```
.with("slot.name", "dbAConnector")
```

And dbBConnector

```
.with("slot.name", "dbBConnector")
```

You can list the available replication slots with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

And you can delete unused replication slot, like the default name "debezium" with:

```
SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('debezium');
```

because will be consuming disk when no one will consume this slot.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you so much! I'll update the code snippets to give a full example. And here is the related [doc](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-slot-name) in case anyone misses it just like I did.